# What will happen with Windows Scheduled Task after disabling\expiration of the windows account created this task?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, user-accounts

I have several scheduled tasks performing different jobs on windows server machine at my current work, but it looks like I'm living this company soon and I have worries about these jobs future after the time when my windows account will be disabled.

Will all gonna be okey with them?

Answer (score 1):

These task's can be run even if you're not there but you have configured that the Task can run "Run whether the user is Logged in or not" or else it is not possible. you can still edit it even after creating it. but I'm not sure it will work even after deleting your account.